# Pytest not able to run test where script A importing another script B in the same folder level as A and giving me ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

I am trying to run the unit test using pytest in this project, here main_0.py is importing s3 file.

I am getting `ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 's3'`

Project Folder Structure

```
    some_project
    └───src
        ├───main
        │   └───lambda_function
        │       └───some
        │               main_0.py
        │               s3.py
        │
        └───test
            └───unittest
                └───lambda_function
                    └───some
                            test_main_0.py
                            test_s3.py
```

main_0.py

```
from s3 import PrintS3

def lambda_handler():
    obj = PrintS3()
    res = obj.print_txt()
    return res
```

s3.py

```
class PrintS3:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.txt = "Hello"

    def print_txt(self):
        print(self.txt)
        return self.txt
```

test_main_0.py

```
import unittest

class TestSomeMain(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_main_0(self):
        from src.main.lambda_function.some.main_0 import lambda_handler
        res = lambda_handler()
        assert res == "Hello"
```

test_s3.py is empty.

I also tried adding an empty `__init__.py` file in both the dir but still the same error
Project Folder Structure after adding `__init__.py` file

```
some_project
└───src
    ├───main
    │   └───lambda_function
    │       └───some
    │               main_0.py
    │               s3.py
    │               __init__.py
    │
    └───test
        └───unittest
            └───lambda_function
                └───some
                        test_main_0.py
                        test_s3.py
                        __init__.py
```

the command I am using to run pytest:

```
python -m pytest ./src/test
```

and I am inside `some_project` folder and also using `main_0.py` instead of `main.py` because to not get confused with main folder

**Edit 2**:

I am to run the test case successfully by adding `sys.path` in the `test_main_0.py` file <s>but it is breaking linting and hinting in the code editor (vscode)</s> it didn't broke the linting and hinting, both import statement works but is there any better way.

new test_main_0.py:

```
import unittest
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("./src/main/lambda_function/some/"))

class TestSomeMain(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_main_0(self):
        from src.main.lambda_function.some.main_0 import lambda_handler # this works
        from main_0 import lambda_handler # this also works but break linting and hinting in the code editor
        res = lambda_handler()
        assert res == "Hello"
```

Comment: Use relative path for s3 import `from . import s3`

Comment: @Shuba thx it worked and passed the unit test I used `from .s3 import PrintS3` but the main code got broken and gave me this error `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` while running it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a somewhat working solution.

added `setUp()` and `tearDown()` methods in the class for inserting and removing path in `sys.path`

path in sys.path is the location of the directory where the main_0.py and s3.py is located

```
import unittest
import os
import sys

class TestSomeMain(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("./src/main/lambda_function/some/"))
    
    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        sys.path.remove(os.path.abspath("./src/main/lambda_function/some/"))

    def test_main_0(self):
        from src.main.lambda_function.some.main_0 import lambda_handler
        res = lambda_handler()
        assert res == "Hello"
```

also update the test command in the terminal:

```
python -m pytest ./src/test/unittest/lambda_function/some --cov ./src/main/lambda_function/some --cov-report html
```

Answer (score 0):

could you please try

```
    import os
    import sys
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".."))

    from some.s3 import PrintS3

    def lambda_handler():
        obj = PrintS3()
        res = obj.print_txt()
        return res
```

Comment: thx it worked but I am looking for a solution that doesn't require changing the main code. I found a somewhat working solution that uses sys.path in the unit test script. I will post the solution soon.